# How do I make a table that prints out in a row all the same columns in a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I am trying to do here is echo out every columns "unit" within my database. In my database I have columns: evaluation, unit, percent and due date. I want all the units to appear on the table in a row as I have tried to do it but can't seem to find out how to do this. this is the code that I have tried `<?php echo $unit ?>` but does not seem to work.
Example

My database:

```
project0     unit1     15%     22-07-2014
project1     unit1     10%     24-07-2014
project2     unit2     20%     27-07-2014
project3     unit3     30%     29-07-2014
```

Code

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('Eviden');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <table width="200" border="1">
    <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM peviden");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $unit=$row['unit'];
            $name=$row['name'];
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
<!--I want all the units columns in the database to go on this row-->
        <td><?php echo $unit ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $unit ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $unit ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $unit ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sebastian</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zack</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Daniel</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the column names to your database sample?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because `mysql_fetch_array` returns an *array*, which would store the results of each row as

`row[0] // evaluation
    row[1] // unit
    row[2] // percent
    row[3] // due date`

Try using the array format, and optionally specify the order for the array as you go:

`<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT evaluation, unit, percent, due_date FROM peviden");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $evaluation=$row[0];
            $unit=$row[1];
            $percent=$row[2];
            $duedate=$row[3];
?>`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is fix your database call. Right now you are looping over the results and assigning $unit a new value at each iteration over the loop. So, we're going to fix that here:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM peviden");

// New Array to avoid PHP notifications
$unitsArray = array();

// Start our loop over our results
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    // Add an entry to our array with two values for unit and name
    $unitsArray[] = array( 'unit' => $row['unit'],
                         'name' => $row['name']
                       );
}
```

Now that we've assigned all our units to a useable value, in your HTML code you need to loop over them again to get them displayed correctly:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<!--I want all the units columns in the database to go on this row-->
<?php
    foreach($unitsArray as $entry) {
?>
    <td><?php echo $entry['unit']; ?></td>
<?php
    }
?>
```

This will create one TD for each unit across the table.